# firebase real time data is not visible after i restored my deleted project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my firebase project got deleted automatically all though I have restored it through the steps provided by google but not I can't see my data in real time database nothing is displayed when I open the project
so please if do anyone know how to recover the data then help me its been 5 hours since I have restored the project

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires accessing the project in question, and thus should be filed with Firebase support.

Comment: firebase has restored the real time data now but the images in storages is not there yet and i don't have access to phone support of google cloud team

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the actual answer if a deleted project only restores the project id or the whole project. However, I would highly suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) as they can asses your project and restore any backups should they exist.

Comment: i have already done that but they haven't replayed to that

Comment: unfortunately, they are the only people who can look at your GCP backend and give a correct answer.

Comment: firebase has restored the real time data now but the images in storages is not there yet and i don't have access to phone support of google cloud team